# displaying large data in asp.net grids

Tags: jquery, grid

I am looking for different ways to present data in gridview that has like 500 - 1000 rows. The grid should support key board navigation. I wrote jquery functions to handle that. But when I am loading 500 rows into the grid, the browser is freezing. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong with the jquery. I can look at the jquery but I was wondering whether it is feasible to have 500 rows in a grid and expect good performance. One option would be to use paging. I would like to hear any other ideas that I might be missing.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and reduce the size of the HTML as much as possible, use CSS classes instead of lots of inline styles and markup.  You should see a pretty good speedup in parsing and rendering time this way (500 rows is not THAT many).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a GridView, try using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater_properties.aspx). This at least will let you have complete control over what is being rendered. GridViews add a lot of bloat to the page in html, ViewState, and included javascript and is usually overkill.

If you were OK with PostBacks, rather than using some custom ajax (not AJAX.Net), for your paging, you can bind the Repeater to a [PagedDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource_properties.aspx) object which can be bound to a DataSet, DataTable, or whatever Collection you're using.

I hope this helps!

---

*Also, a GridView should be able to handle 500 rows without your browser freezing. Can you post your jQuery?*